# How to collect from streams on multi condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Category> category = categoryRepository.findRootCategories(scope.getValue())
        .map(Category::getMasterCategory)
        .map(Category::getCode)
        .filter(code -> code.equalsIgnoreCase(orderType))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any thing wrong with this?
I am getting compilation error. I wanted to filter the categories returned by `findRootCategories` method on two conditions

1. get the master category first
2. Compare the code of master category with some input

error: method collect in class Observable cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete, runnable, minimal example which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Ask yourself: After `.map(Category::getCode)`, what's the type of my `Stream`?

Comment: @tgdavies its String, how to get its Parent which is return element of findRootCategories method?

Comment: Just write your filter so that it works on a `Category`.

Comment: @user2555212 you need to rewrite it from `.map(Category::getCode).filter(code -> code.equalsIgnoreCase(orderType))` to `.filter(category -> category.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(orderType))`, which will keep your stream elements' type as `Category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing this `.map(Category::getCode)` Stream type will be return type of `getCode()`. Suppose `getCode()` return string then collecting as List it will return `List<String>`.

```
List<Category> category = categoryRepository
        .findRootCategories(scope.getValue())              // Stream<Category>
        .map(Category::getMasterCategory)                  // Stream<Category>
        .map(Category::getCode)                            // Stream<String>
        .filter(code -> code.equalsIgnoreCase(orderType))  // Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                     // List<String>
```

To check the condition on filter doing this `.map(Category::getCode)` is unnecessary. You can directly check inside the filter (as @ernest_k suggested) then the Stream type remain `Category`

```
List<Category> category = categoryRepository
        .findRootCategories(scope.getValue())                      // Stream<Category>
        .map(Category::getMasterCategory)                          // Stream<Category>
        .filter(category -> category.getCode()
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(orderType))  // Stream<Category>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                             // List<Category>
```